# Escaping local optima in OptaPlanner task scheduling

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am basically [still trying to create a timeline of tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448116/task-scheduling-gets-stuck/23466584) (with a certain duration) that has flexible, you could say "stretchy" links between tasks, e.g. task B has to be between 5 and 10 minutes after task B. Also tasks can't overlap, as a person can only work on one thing at every moment.

There are also some additional features I might need to incorporate later on which I include here just in case they are or will be relevant at some point:

- task durations might become flexible in a certain range
- certain tasks may be locked to a certain point in time
- you may add new people so that you can have two tasks done simultaneously

**My Problem** is that my approach easily gets stuck in local optimas.

What I currently do is optimizing the start times of tasks with having a hard constraint that is how much links are outside range and if they overlap. This seems to work well and mostly quickly finds a solution that doesn't break any hard constraints.
My additional soft constraint should try to minimize the overall duration of the process. If e.g. the link between Task B and C is 20-100 minutes the hardscore doesn't care if the link is 20 or 100 minutes. But generally 20 is better than 100. BUT when dealing with complex tree-like dependencies of tasks it might be better to use a 80 minutes link to put some other task in that gap so some third later task can start earlier. So just minimizing link-length isn't a working approach.
But the problem is that once a link is inside the range there is no incentive to move it out of that range to maybe later get to a better solution. I am stuck in a local optima.

Therefore I am now thinking about how to solve this issue.The approach I have been thinking of and where I am hoping for feedback is creating a new CompositeMove that moves two linked tasks. This improves the situation but doesn't scale well as we end up in the same situation as soon as three or more tasks are tightly linked.

Another thing I have been thinking of is trying to implement a move that takes a task, stretches a link and puts the task in the gap. I haven't really thought this through properly though.

I also messed around with different local search approaches, but this also didn't really help. But I assume that they can't really help here anyway.

I have also looked at [OptaPlanner vehicle routing and relations between customer visits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501486/optaplanner-vehicle-routing-and-relations-between-customer-visits/19511732#19511732) but while it helped me understand the problem it didn't really help with a solution.

Comment: I presume you also looked at the Project Job Scheduling example?

Comment: In the academic papers, there's an alternative approach that works well for PJS, which I haven't implemented in OptaPlanner yet: Given an ordered list of the jobs (= tasks), use a deterministic construction heuristic to place them greedily. Then use Local Search to reorder that list. This approach sometimes discards solutions, but for MISTA2013 (the competition behind Project Job Scheduling), it had promising results.

Comment: Practically speaking though (unless you're a metaheursitic expert), I 'd recommend to just add course grained moves and use the benchmarker to see which ones are worth adding. And wait until OptaPlanner supports the approach above out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have read through the PJS example a couple of times but still haven't really understood what is going on (so definitely also not a metaheuristic expert) I think this might be because there are a lot of stuff I'm ignoring for now (mainly resources) while my flexible links do not exist.

Comment: Is there an example of creating a custom MoveListFactory besides [the one in the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#moveListFactory)? I didn't manage creating a new CompositeMove yet because I don't know how to create a new ChangeMove. What should `variableDescriptor` and `toPlanningValue` be? Or do I have to create a new move even if I just need a CompositeMove of ChangeMoves?

Comment: you don't need to create a new move selector implementation just to have a composite move of change moves. Use cartesianProductMoveSelector (possibly with mimic recording) instead. See section "7.6.8. Mimic selection (record/replay)" and section "7.3.2. cartesianProductMoveSelector" in the latest docs.

Comment: I have tried that, but how can I select two different tasks that are linked? Mimic selection lets me do 2 moves on one entity. And with cartesianProductMoveSelector I can move to tasks at the same time. But how do I move two linked tasks together? Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: 2 different task that are linked is nearbySelection (there's a jira for that, not yet implemented, on my todo list for 6.1 or 6.2). Workaround is a custom MoveListFactory or MoveIteratorFactory...

Comment: Again hoping not to ask dumb questions...when I create a custom MoveListFactory can I use existing move types? Because if yes [what are the needed parameters here](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/069d9cd8aeff496eca571274525c414367c9c26f/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/heuristic/selector/move/generic/ChangeMove.java#L35-L36) `GenuineVariableDescriptor variableDescriptor, Object toPlanningValue` Or do I need to create a new Move?

Comment: You can reuse existing move type's, but it's not self evident... Create a jira for that (see optaplanner.org -> report issue). Meanwhile see bottom of NQueensPanel.java.